# Non standard join

Tags: database, join, relational-algebra

I ran into a problem and was trying to find a general solution to it as a join.

I have 2 tables :

http://pastebin.com/q5yws5Ym (not sure how to enforce the styling)

And i want to generate something like 
http://pastebin.com/GscBUrYS

(while there are more parameters i'm interested in how i would do it for something like this)

While i was able to reach a similar effect with self-joins and equi-joins it would generate a lot of unneeded rows, which i'm not sure how to delete automatically.

Comment: Is the amount of parameters per user fixed or may it be that one user has two parameters, one four, etc.?

Comment: The amount of parameters is same for all users. (fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
SELECT user.user_id, j1.user_param, j1.user_value, j2.user_param, j2.user_value
FROM user
JOIN Users_info j1 ON user.user_id = j1.user_id
JOIN users_info j2 on user.user_id = j2.user_id
where j1.user_param != j2.user_param
GROUP BY user.user_id
```

It may be possible that you will need some more "exclusion" clauses for the where to make sure that every row is only selected once but the general idea should work (for a given and limited number of different  user_param`s).

Comment: so given 3 param's it would be something along the lines of

`SELECT user.user_id, j1.user_param, j1.user_value, j2.user_param, j2.user_value , j3.user_param, j3.user_value
FROM user
JOIN Users_info j1 ON user.user_id = j1.user_id
JOIN users_info j2 on user.user_id = j2.user_id
JOIN users_info j3 on user.user_id = j3.user_id
where j1.user_param != j2.user_param and j1.user_param != j3.user_param and j2.user_param != j3.user_param
GROUP BY user.user_id`

Comment: Yes, something like that. I don't have a database server at hand but I also think that it will depend on the actual server.

Comment: Thank you, i will look into it. (trying to find a more abstract / relational algebra solution)